# How do I get all the bananas on level 21 without blind luck?

Tags: blast-monkeys

How do I get all of the bananas on level 21 of the Jungle world in Blast Monkeys without just firing the monkey until I get lucky?

I've been trying for a while and the best I've been able to get has been 2 out of the 3 bananas, and that was just down to luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just aim almost straight up at the highest banana... you will bounce over to the left and get the next one on hte way down then bounce of the rock to the bubble then tap the bubble once you are almost back to the third banana and you will drop to the rock again breaking it and bouncing over to the other bubble then just ride it all the way to the left and tap it to drop on bunch.